# When I add a left:0 div my right:0 div disapears

Tags: html, position, absolute

I try to add some div(s) to the sides of the main div for that I have

```
#maindiv ( position:relative)

#borderright (
position: absolute;
background: red;
width: 3px;
height: 100%;
right: 0)

#borderleft(
position: absolute;
background: red;
width: 3px;
height: 100%;
left:0)
```

now when I do

```
      <div id="maindiv">
    <div id="borderright">
</div>
        <div id="rightborder">
</div>
    <div id="leftborder">
</div>

</div>
```

Their is only 1 div showing ( the left one) if I delete the left div the right one is showing...

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help :)

Edit: When I look to the css with Chrome, it seems that div id rightborder style is empty, and if I had the styles myself in view mode it works !? Again, if I delet the left di (leftborder) the rightborder is showing up... Weird isn't it ?

Edit2: The thing that suprise me the most is that when adding one div it delete the style of the other, when checking with chrome I have:
rightborder:()